# Non-Assert Way To Compare Two 2D Arrays for Accuracy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array, scipy

I am currently training a LSTM which classifies frames. What I am trying to do is compare two 2d numpy arrays to check for accuracy between my prediction and target. I have currently looked around for non-naive ways to solve this problem using NumPy / SciPy.

I am aware that there is np.testing.assert_array_equal(x, y) which uses Assertion to output the results. I am looking for a way to solve this issue using NumPy / SciPy so I can store the results rather than an Assert print out:

```
Arrays are not equal

(mismatch 14.285714285714292%)
 x: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
 y: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

```
x = np.asarray([[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]])

y = np.asarray([[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]])

try:
    np.testing.assert_array_equal(x, y)
    res = True
except AssertionError as err:
    res = False
    print (err)
```

I am looking for a way which I can store the mismatch of these two arrays without using a naive fashion (Two comparative loops):

```
accuracy = thisFunction(x,y)
```

I am sure there is something in NumPy which can solve this, I've had no luck with searching for built-in functions.

Comment: Look at `np.all_close`

Comment: Wait, stack overflow markdown allows triple backticks now? That's awesome!

Answer (score 0):

As hpaulj noted in the comment, you can use [`numpy.allclose()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html) for checking the array equality, with acceptable difference of up to some tolerance value (see below or NumPy notes).

Here is a small illustration with two simple float arrays.

```
In [7]: arr1 = np.array([1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 3.4]) 
In [8]: arr2 = np.array([1.299999, 1.4, 1.4999999, 3.3999999999]) 

In [9]: np.allclose(arr1, arr2) 
Out[9]: True
```

[numpy.allclose](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html) will return `True` if the corresponding elements in the arrays are dissimilar (only up to the tolerance value). Else it would return `False`. NumPy default for relative & absolute tolerance values are `rtol=1e-05`, `atol=1e-08` respectively.

---

Having said that, if you only want to compare `int` arrays, then you'd be better off with [`numpy.array_equal()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.array_equal.html) which is approx. 8x faster than [`numpy.allclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html).

```
In [17]: arr1 = np.random.randint(23045) 
In [18]: arr2 = np.random.randint(23045) 

In [19]: %timeit np.allclose(arr1, arr2) 
22.9 µs ± 471 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [20]: %timeit np.array_equal(arr1, arr2) 
3.99 µs ± 68.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: This is not optimal for comparing the equality of integer arrays.

Comment: @MadPhysicist thanks, I updated the answer with an alternative.

Comment: OP changed the question to not be a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

[`np.array_equal(x, y)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_equal.html) is roughly equivalent to `(x == y).all()`. You can use this to compute the discrepancies:

```
def array_comp(x, y):
    """
    Return the status of the comparison and the discrepancy.

    For arrays of the same shape, the discrepancy is a ratio of mismatches to the total size.
    For arrays of different shapes or sizes, the discrepancy is a message indicating the mismatch.
    """
    if x.shape != y.shape:
        return False, 'shape'
    count = x.size - np.count_nonzero(x == y)
    return count == 0, count / x.size
```